# how would i get rid off this error "OSError: [WinError 123] The filename,"

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am working on a project, and when I run the server I get this error :

> OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label
>   syntax is incorrect

But before this there is another error :

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dep.urls'

I am using Django 2.2.3, Python 3.6.8 and MySQL 5.7.26. In the previous version of Django(2.1.8) it was working fine. When I searched on Google I found that in the newer version of Django there is a new way of mapping to the urls. I am pretty sure that the solution of my problem is [Django 2.2 breaks previously working views/urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55481810/django-2-2-breaks-previously-working-views-urls?noredirect=1&lq=1).

When I open the described file, I don't find where to edit, what is being said is not available in the file. Any help would be appreciated.

## urls

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
path('',include('dep.urls')),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

]

[image: Traceback]